# Why does the loop iterate after deleting the reference to the iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, reference, del

I am using Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10.
I have the following code:

```py
x = range(5)

for i in x:
    print(i)
    del x
```

Expected Output:

```py
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Students\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in x:
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Actual Output:

```py
0
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Students\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    del x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

On the first iteration I would expect `del x` would delete `x` so that on the second iteration it would give me error on the line, `for i in x:`.
However, it keeps iterating, printing out `1`, then gives me error on the line, `del x`.
It seems like it works the same way with any iterables. I tested with dicts, sets, tuples, and lists.

Am I missing something here?
Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: Because the loop already holds its own reference, it doesn't go "back" to `x` each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop isn't actually working with `x`; it's working with the return value of `iter(x)`, which *itself* holds a reference to the same object as `x`. Deleting `x` doesn't affect that reference.

`del x` only decrements the reference count of the object referenced by `x`, and if that reference count reaches 0, the object is subject to garbage collection. It does not immediately destroy the object.

The *first* time through the loop, the name `x` is still defined. That name is removed, though, by `del x`, so on the *second* iteration, `del x` produces the `NameError`.

---

You can think of this `for` loop as being roughly equivalent to

```
x_iter = iter(x)
while True:
    try:
        i = next(x_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        del x_iter  # Clean up the namespace before exiting the loop
        break
    print(i)
    del x
```

(roughly, because unlike the name `x_iter` in this loop, the iterator used by the `for` loop as no Python-visible reference).